# .NET MAUI: Customize datepicker so that it opens when clicking on an icon

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

I want to display a calendar icon, then when the user taps/clicks the calendar icon, the date picker opens up. Is there a way to customize the date picker to implement this functionality?
Do I need a custom handler?

I tried calling Focus() on the date picker, but it didn't open up.

```xml
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker" MinimumDate="01/01/2022"
                MaximumDate="12/31/2022"
                Date="06/21/2022" />
                <ImageButton Source="calendar.svg" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"></ImageButton>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
```

```
    private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDatePicker.Focus();
    }
```

*Note:* The icon is from: https://feathericons.com/?query=calendar

Comment: Please show enough of your code so that people can see what you've attempted already.

Comment: So the thing is that there is an open issue with the Focus event of Maui controls that it does not act as it used to in Xamarin Forms, My understanding is they might be planning to recalibrate this in Maui or adding a different API that does this, So for now its an open issue, As far as it comes to having a DatePicker with an Image you could use my controls here: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls they have the option to add images in your drawable ports : github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls, Known issue of focus event https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing Maui.FreakyControls and a custom behavior resulted in this solution for Android.
It does require a custom handler to implement successfully.

MauiProgram.cs

```
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            })
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
                handlers.AddCustomHandlers();
            });

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Shared/Extensions/Extensions.cs

```
#if ANDROID
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
using static Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform;
using NativeImage = Android.Graphics.Bitmap;
#endif

        public static void ExecuteCommandIfAvailable(this ICommand command, object parameter = null)
        {
            if (command?.CanExecute(parameter) == true)
            {
                command.Execute(parameter);
            }
        }

        public static void AddCustomHandlers(this IMauiHandlersCollection handlers)
        {
#if ANDROID
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Maui.CustomControls.CustomDatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerHandler));
#endif
        }
#if ANDROID
        public static async Task<NativeImage> ToNativeImageSourceAsync(this ImageSource source)
        {
            var handler = GetHandler(source);
            var returnValue = (NativeImage)null;

            returnValue = await handler.LoadImageAsync(source, CurrentActivity);

            return returnValue;
        }

        private static IImageSourceHandler GetHandler(this ImageSource source)
        {
            //Image source handler to return 
            IImageSourceHandler returnValue = null;
            //check the specific source type and return the correct image source handler 
            switch (source)
            {
                case UriImageSource:
                    returnValue = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
                    break;
                case FileImageSource:
                    returnValue = new FileImageSourceHandler();
                    break;
                case StreamImageSource:
                    returnValue = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
                    break;
                case FontImageSource:
                    returnValue = new FontImageSourceHandler();
                    break;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
#endif
```

Android/NativeControls/Helpers/DrawableHandlerCallback.cs

```
    public class DrawableHandlerCallback : IDrawableClickListener
    {
        private readonly IDrawableImageView view;
        private readonly Action showPicker;

        public DrawableHandlerCallback(IDrawableImageView view, Action showPicker)
        {
            this.view = view;
            this.showPicker = showPicker;
        }

        public void OnClick(DrawablePosition target)
        {
            switch (target)
            {
                case DrawablePosition.Left:
                case DrawablePosition.Right:
                    view.ImageTappedHandler.Invoke(this.showPicker, null);
                    view.ImageCommand?.ExecuteCommandIfAvailable(view.ImageCommandParameter);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Android/NativeControls/Helpers/DrawablePosition.cs

```
public enum DrawablePosition
    {
        Top,
        Bottom,
        Left,
        Right
    };
```

Android/NativeControls/Helpers/IDrawableClickListener.cs

```
public interface IDrawableClickListener
    {
        public void OnClick(DrawablePosition target);
    }
```

Android/NativeControls/CustomMauiDatePicker.cs

```
public class CustomMauiDatePicker : MauiDatePicker
    {
        private Drawable drawableRight;
        private Drawable drawableLeft;
        private Drawable drawableTop;
        private Drawable drawableBottom;

        int actionX, actionY;

        private IDrawableClickListener clickListener;

        public CustomMauiDatePicker(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        public CustomMauiDatePicker(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {

        }

        public CustomMauiDatePicker(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {

        }

        public override void SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top,
               Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
        {
            if (left != null)
            {
                drawableLeft = left;
            }
            if (right != null)
            {
                drawableRight = right;
            }
            if (top != null)
            {
                drawableTop = top;
            }
            if (bottom != null)
            {
                drawableBottom = bottom;
            }
            base.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Rect bounds;
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                actionX = (int)e.GetX();
                actionY = (int)e.GetY();
                if (drawableBottom != null
                    && drawableBottom.Bounds.Contains(actionX, actionY))
                {
                    clickListener.OnClick(DrawablePosition.Bottom);
                    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
                }

                if (drawableTop != null
                        && drawableTop.Bounds.Contains(actionX, actionY))
                {
                    clickListener.OnClick(DrawablePosition.Top);
                    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
                }

                // this works for left since container shares 0,0 origin with bounds
                if (drawableLeft != null)
                {
                    bounds = null;
                    bounds = drawableLeft.Bounds;

                    int x, y;
                    int extraTapArea = (int)(13 * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density + 0.5);

                    x = actionX;
                    y = actionY;

                    if (!bounds.Contains(actionX, actionY))
                    {
                        // Gives the +20 area for tapping. /
                        x = (int)(actionX - extraTapArea);
                        y = (int)(actionY - extraTapArea);

                        if (x <= 0)
                            x = actionX;
                        if (y <= 0)
                            y = actionY;

                        // Creates square from the smallest value /
                        if (x < y)
                        {
                            y = x;
                        }
                    }

                    if (bounds.Contains(x, y) && clickListener != null)
                    {
                        clickListener.OnClick(DrawablePosition.Left);
                        e.Action = (MotionEventActions.Cancel);
                        return false;

                    }
                }

                if (drawableRight != null)
                {

                    bounds = null;
                    bounds = drawableRight.Bounds;

                    int x, y;
                    int extraTapArea = 13;

                    //
                    //  IF USER CLICKS JUST OUT SIDE THE RECTANGLE OF THE DRAWABLE
                    //  THAN ADD X AND SUBTRACT THE Y WITH SOME VALUE SO THAT AFTER
                    //  CALCULATING X AND Y CO-ORDINATE LIES INTO THE DRAWBABLE
                    //  BOUND. - this process help to increase the tappable area of
                    //  the rectangle.
                    // 
                    x = (int)(actionX + extraTapArea);
                    y = (int)(actionY - extraTapArea);

                    //Since this is right drawable subtract the value of x from the width 
                    // of view. so that width - tappedarea will result in x co-ordinate in drawable bound. 
                    //
                    x = Width - x;

                    //x can be negative if user taps at x co-ordinate just near the width.
                    // e.g views width = 300 and user taps 290. Then as per previous calculation
                    // 290 + 13 = 303. So subtract X from getWidth() will result in negative value.
                    // So to avoid this add the value previous added when x goes negative.
                    //

                    if (x <= 0)
                    {
                        x += extraTapArea;
                    }

                    // If result after calculating for extra tappable area is negative.
                    // assign the original value so that after subtracting
                    // extratapping area value doesn't go into negative value.
                    //

                    if (y <= 0)
                        y = actionY;

                    //If drawble bounds contains the x and y points then move ahead./
                    if (bounds.Contains(x, y) && clickListener != null)
                    {
                        clickListener
                                .OnClick(DrawablePosition.Right);
                        e.Action = (MotionEventActions.Cancel);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
                }

            }
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }

        protected override void JavaFinalize()
        {
            drawableRight = null;
            drawableBottom = null;
            drawableLeft = null;
            drawableTop = null;
            base.JavaFinalize();
        }

        public void SetDrawableClickListener(IDrawableClickListener listener)
        {
            this.clickListener = listener;
        }
    }
```

Platforms/Android/CustomDatePickerHandler.android.cs

```
public partial class CustomDatePickerHandler
    {
        DatePickerDialog? _dialog;

        protected override MauiDatePicker CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var mauiDatePicker = new CustomMauiDatePicker(Context)
            {
                ShowPicker = ShowPickerDialog,
                HidePicker = HidePickerDialog
            };

            var date = VirtualView?.Date;

            if (date != null)
                _dialog = CreateDatePickerDialog(date.Value.Year, date.Value.Month, date.Value.Day);
            var colorStateList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(mauiDatePicker, colorStateList);
            return mauiDatePicker;
        }

        protected override void DisconnectHandler(MauiDatePicker platformView)
        {
            base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
            if (_dialog != null)
            {
                _dialog.Hide();
                _dialog.Dispose();
                _dialog = null;
            }
        }

        internal DatePickerDialog? DatePickerDialog { get { return _dialog; } }

        internal async Task HandleAndAlignImageSourceAsync(Maui.CustomControls.CustomDatePicker entry)
        {
            var imageBitmap = await entry.ImageSource?.ToNativeImageSourceAsync();
            if (imageBitmap != null)
            {
                var bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Platform.CurrentActivity?.Resources,
                    Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, entry.ImageWidth * 2, entry.ImageHeight * 2, true));
                var customDatePicker = PlatformView as CustomMauiDatePicker;
                customDatePicker.SetDrawableClickListener(new DrawableHandlerCallback(entry, customDatePicker.ShowPicker));
                switch (entry.ImageAlignment)
                {
                    case ImageAlignment.Left:
                        customDatePicker.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(bitmapDrawable, null, null, null);
                        break;
                    case ImageAlignment.Right:
                        customDatePicker.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, bitmapDrawable, null);
                        break;
                }
            }
            PlatformView.CompoundDrawablePadding = entry.ImagePadding;
        }


        void ShowPickerDialog()
        {
            if (VirtualView == null)
                return;

            if (_dialog != null && _dialog.IsShowing)
                return;

            var date = VirtualView.Date;
            ShowPickerDialog(date.Year, date.Month - 1, date.Day);
        }

        void ShowPickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            if (_dialog == null)
                _dialog = CreateDatePickerDialog(year, month, day);
            else
            {
                EventHandler? setDateLater = null;
                setDateLater = (sender, e) => { _dialog!.UpdateDate(year, month, day); _dialog.ShowEvent -= setDateLater; };
                _dialog.ShowEvent += setDateLater;
            }

            _dialog.Show();
        }

        void HidePickerDialog()
        {
            _dialog?.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Shared/Controls/IDrawableImageView.cs

```
public interface IDrawableImageView
    {
        public EventHandler ImageTappedHandler
        {
            get;
        }

        public object ImageCommandParameter
        {
            get;
        }

        public ICommand ImageCommand
        {
            get;
        }

        public int ImagePadding
        {
            get;
        }

        public int ImageWidth
        {
            get;
        }

        public int ImageHeight
        {
            get;
        }

        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get;
        }

        public ImageAlignment ImageAlignment
        {
            get;
        }
    }
```

Shared/CustomDatePicker/CustomDatePicker.cs

```
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker, IDrawableImageView
    {

        private EventHandler imageTapped;
        public EventHandler ImageTappedHandler
        {
            get { return imageTapped; }
        }
        public event EventHandler ImageTapped
        {
            add
            {
                imageTapped += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                imageTapped -= value;
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Image),
                typeof(ImageSource),
                typeof(CustomDatePicker),
                default(ImageSource));

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageHeightProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(ImageHeight),
               typeof(int),
               typeof(CustomDatePicker),
               25);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(ImageWidth),
               typeof(int),
               typeof(CustomDatePicker),
               25);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageAlignmentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(ImageAlignment),
               typeof(ImageAlignment),
               typeof(CustomDatePicker),
               ImageAlignment.Right);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImagePaddingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(ImagePadding),
               typeof(int),
               typeof(CustomDatePicker),
               5);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
              nameof(ImagePadding),
              typeof(ICommand),
              typeof(CustomDatePicker),
              default(ICommand));

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageCommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
              nameof(ImageCommandParameter),
              typeof(object),
              typeof(CustomDatePicker),
              default(object));

        /// <summary>
        /// Command parameter for your Image tap command 
        /// </summary>
        public object ImageCommandParameter
        {
            get => GetValue(ImageCommandParameterProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageCommandParameterProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="ImageCommand"/> of type <see cref="ICommand"/> that you can use to bind with your Image that you added to your control's ViewPort
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ImageCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(ImageCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageCommandProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Padding of the Image as <see cref="int"/> that you added to the ViewPort
        /// </summary>
        public int ImagePadding
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ImagePaddingProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImagePaddingProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Width of the Image in your ViewPort
        /// </summary>
        public int ImageWidth
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ImageWidthProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageWidthProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Height of the Image in your ViewPort
        /// </summary>
        public int ImageHeight
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// An <see cref="ImageSource"/> that you want to add to your ViewPort
        /// </summary>
        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="ImageAlignment"/> for your Image's ViewPort, By default set to Right.
        /// </summary>
        public ImageAlignment ImageAlignment
        {
            get => (ImageAlignment)GetValue(ImageAlignmentProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageAlignmentProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Shared/CustomDatePickerHandler/CustomDatePickerHandler.cs

```
#if ANDROID
    public partial class CustomDatePickerHandler : DatePickerHandler
    {
        public CustomDatePickerHandler()
        {
            Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomDatePickerCustomization", MapDatePicker);
        }

        private void MapDatePicker(IDatePickerHandler datePickerHandler, IDatePicker datePicker)
        {
            if (datePicker is Maui.CustomControls.CustomDatePicker customDatePicker &&
                datePickerHandler is CustomDatePickerHandler customDatePickerHandler)
            {
                if (customDatePicker.ImageSource != default(ImageSource))
                {
                    customDatePickerHandler.HandleAndAlignImageSourceAsync(customDatePicker).RunConcurrently();
                }
            }
        }
    }

#endif
```

Shared/Enums/ImageAlignment.cs

```
public enum ImageAlignment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Aligns your control to the left view port of the view. 
        /// </summary>
        Left,

        /// <summary>
        /// Aligns your control to the right view port of the view.
        /// </summary>
        Right
    }
```

Shared/Extensions/TaskExtensions.cs

```
public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        public static void RunConcurrently(this Task task)
        {
            if (task == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("task", "task is null.");

            if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                task.Start();
        }
    }
```

CustomDatePickerPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout Padding="10,60,10,0">
        <Label Text="Please enter a date."
               FontSize="12" />
        <custom:CustomDatePicker MinimumDate="01/01/2022"
                                         MaximumDate="12/31/2022"
                                         Date="06/21/2022"
                                         ImageSource="calendar"
                                         ImageAlignment="Right"
                                         ImageHeight="40"
                                         ImageWidth="40"
                                         ImagePadding="10"
                                         FontSize="Large">
            <custom:CustomDatePicker.Behaviors>
                <local:CustomDatePickerBehavior />
            </custom:CustomDatePicker.Behaviors>
        </custom:CustomDatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
```

Behaviors/CustomDatePickerBehavior.cs

```
public class CustomDatePickerBehavior : Behavior<CustomDatePicker>
    {
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(CustomDatePicker picker)
        {
            picker.ImageTapped += Picker_ImageTapped;
            base.OnAttachedTo(picker);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(CustomDatePicker picker)
        {
            picker.ImageTapped -= Picker_ImageTapped;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(picker);
        }

        private void Picker_ImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Action showPicker = (Action)sender;
            showPicker.Invoke();
        }
    }
```